# Can't access a variable in python from a bash function

Tags: python, bash, function, variables

I'm setting a bash variable in the main shell by reading the content of a file with

```
srclang="$(cat ${langdir}/srclang.log)
```

The value is "en-GB" and it prints just fine.

I then call a function that, in turn, calls a python script, but when I try to access this variable with

```
os.environ["srclang"]
```

From the python script, I get the following error

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'srclang'
```

How can I pass this variable from the function to the python script?

EDIT:

After reading a little more on it, it seems like I have to export it, but exporting is also giving me an error:

```
export: `en-GB': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: Did you `export` that variable or explicitly set it for the Python process…?

Comment: Exporting doesn't seem to work and I can't understand why. How do I set it explicitly for python?

Comment: How exactly did you `export` that…? It's supposed to go like `export srclang="en-GB"` or just `export srclang`…

Comment: you have to `export srclang=$(cat ${langdir}/srclang.log)`

Comment: I was setting it with that first command in my question and then running "export srclang" separately, which gave me that error.
By runnning it in a single (and more elegant) line like sam proposed, it worked, thank you both.